# VPN connecting offices vs hiding only VPNs (privacy) and their settings

Tags: vpn, data

What's actually difference in settings of VPN when it's used e.g. to connect the company's offices around the world with the headquarters and VPN you just connect to hide what you do on the Internet?

question 1) Is it the same, but in those VPNs that are used only for privacy, the **data sharing is disabled** between the connected computers?

question 2) Can other people on VPNs like hotspotshield or other free or paid VPNs see me on the network or access my files on the computer somehow or the owner of the VPN?

How can one set-up a simple VPN? Just point me to a software or something that can manage that.

Thanks in advance, i am just a newbie into networking and want to get it sorted out.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A VPN is just a tunnel which encapsulates, and optionally encrypts, your IP packets inside other IP packets. Different VPN creators add different options to their software, but a VPN tunnel operates the the same from a network perspective - encapsulate IP packets inside other IP packets.

Questions about the actual applications or recommendations for such are off-topic, and you can ask those questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).